# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when calling method on Firebase reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access, firebase

I'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS whenever I try to call a method on one of my Firebase objects. Here is the line it is currently crashing on:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[self.ref description]);
```

I've made sure self.ref is not nil. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: here is its property declaration: `@property (strong, nonatomic)Firebase* ref;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by enabling ARC. I went to the build settings and set Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting to Yes.